# Unable to connect $GET['page']

Tags: php

Hey i've got a problem.

This is my code:

```
<?php
    define('IN_INDEX', 1);
    include ('inc.php');
    $GET['page'] == ('themes/<?php echo $theme; ?>/index') or 
    die ("Unable to connect");
?>
```

Previously this code got the `$theme` variable from the config, which is required in `inc.php`, and then show the index of the theme, but now it fails with `Unable to connect` .

Comment: ^^ and the syntax is borked

Comment: and 'themes/'.  $theme; .'/index'

Comment: @galchen, Doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you meant

```
if ($_GET['page'] == 'themes/'.$theme.'/index'){
// ?
}else{
// ?
}
```

Comment: that response tells us nothing of use.

Comment: I mean i still get the same error, now i have it like this?

<?php
define('IN_INDEX', 1);
include ('inc.php');


if ($_GET['page'] == 'themes/'.$theme.'/index'){

}else{



die ("Unable to connect");}

Comment: You copy-pasted part of this answer incorrectly, it should be `$theme`, not `theme`.

Comment: then either $_GET['page'] or $theme, is not what you think it is or should be